# Turn multiple columns into one column value DAX/PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to turn multiple columns into one column value DAX/PowerBI.

I have a `table1` with some columns name `Phone No.1`, `Phone No.2`, `Phone No.3`, `Phone No.4`, `Phone No.5`, `Phone No.6` and also `table 2` with the columns name `Phone No.1`, `Phone No.2`, `Phone No.3`, `Phone No.4`, `Phone No.5`, `Phone No.6`.

Now I would like to have a table with a column of unique values from all those columns.

I have search a lot to find a solution, but unfortunately, It seems like there is no solution to this challenge!

Do anyone knows any way or any solution to solve this challenge!

Comment: Look for type of join that suits you. Inner perhaps. Dplyr package has them implemented.

Comment: Could also be done in DAX or Power Query (Grouping and Joins). If you could post a minimal sample of your tables and the expected output, I could help you maybe more.

Comment: @Strawberryshrub thank you for your help. But it seems like the following thing works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping it simple, you can try following in DAX (Calculated Table):

```
New Table = 
VAR newTable = 
UNION (
    SUMMARIZE(table1, table1[Phone No.1]),
    SUMMARIZE(table1, table1[Phone No.2]),
    SUMMARIZE(table1, table1[Phone No.3]),
    SUMMARIZE(table1, table1[Phone No.4]),
    SUMMARIZE(table1, table1[Phone No.5]),
    SUMMARIZE(table1, table1[Phone No.6]),
    SUMMARIZE(table2, table1[Phone No.1]),
    SUMMARIZE(table2, table1[Phone No.2]),
    SUMMARIZE(table2, table1[Phone No.3]),
    SUMMARIZE(table2, table1[Phone No.4]),
    SUMMARIZE(table2, table1[Phone No.5]),
    SUMMARIZE(table2, table1[Phone No.6])
)

RETURN 
    SUMMARIZE(newTable, table1[Phone No.1])
```